# User avatar not shown in meteor react

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am prototyping new Meteor-React app. Images are stored in S3. They are accessible by url. There is not yet subscription added, autopublish is not removed yet. To add reactive behavior to React, as suggested in tutorial, `react-addons-pure-render-mixin` and `react-meteor-data` are added to project. I understand, that user.profile is not instantly available, so there is a check:

```
avatarUrl(){
    var user = Meteor.user();
    return (user&&user.profile?Meteor.user().profile.avatar:"/no-thumb2.jpg");
}
```

At my page I have the following code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <header>
                <h1>...</h1>
            </header>

            <Image ref="ava" src={this.avatarUrl()} height="171" width="180" circle title="..." />
```

But the result is no-image `no-thumb2.jpg` thumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your component with a Container component in order to utilize reactive data from `react-meteor-data`. Let's say your Component is called `App`, it could look something like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Image ref="ava" src={this.props.avatar} height="171" width="180" circle title="..." />
    )
  }
}

// CONTAINER that wraps App
export default AppContainer = createContainer( ({}) => {
  const user = Meteor.user();
  const avatar = (user&&user.profile?Meteor.user().profile.avatar:"/no-thumb2.jpg");

  return {
    avatar
  }
}, App);
```

You then use `AppContainer` instead of `App`. That should reactively update your avatar. You can learn more about this approach [here](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer). Also you can use anonymous containers, but I like this approach as it is clearer.

Comment: Glad to hear @Dmitry :-) Can you accept the answer? Thank you!